# Normal Distribution question - Finding MEAN from given SD and Area

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, means

Have been stuck on this question for weeks now, and I really need help with the solution.

The volume of a soft drink in a 1-litre bottle is normally distributed. The filling machine needs to be calibrated so that no more than 2% of bottles are more than 2mL under volume. Standard deviation = 2.5mL. What should the target volume be (mean) ?

SPOILER OF ANSWER:
Answer = 1003mL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is requesting that

$$\mathbb{P}[X<998]\leq 0.02$$

$$\mathbb{P}[Z<\frac{998-\mu}{2.5}]\leq 0.02$$

reading the quantile on the Standard Gaussian Table

$$\frac{998-\mu}{2.5}\leq -2.0537$$

$$\mu\geq 1003.1344$$

Comment: thank you so much!

Comment: If I were to do this on a calculator would I use inverse norm func?

Comment: @AishaSchreiber :Yes